# Google calendar api creating event return Calendar usage limits exceeded

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, apex

Here is the error message:

> "code": 403,   "message": "Calendar usage limits exceeded."

But when I check in google developer console, there is no API limitation being hit. And have nowhere to check what is the limitation I am facing.

(I am creating around 150 events per day, I have a master account, and I using this account for inserting events for other account under the same domain, any suggestions are welcome)

Comment: Did you check on per-user limits for your application? check this link https://developers.google.com/console/help/new/  Also, instead of sending too many requests at a time, you can use exponential backoff https://developers.google.com/drive/web/handle-errors

Comment: For the future reference, the help center article explaining this error is here: https://support.google.com/a/answer/2905486?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

After two days intense testing, finally find the error, we have an same attendee for every event, after delete this attendee, everything works again.